# Can we have a defined format for answers to 'first/earliest' type questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There's a well defined format for code golf questions over at [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

> **Mouse-2002**, 4 bytes.
>
> That's 4 bytes of pure, sweet ASCII.
> ...
> [Sample question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66078/9534)

I'd propose a similar construct of

> **Title**, *Author*, Year
> *Justification for meeting the question's criteria*

This should make it easier for people coming to the question to see if it's worth answering.

In the best case scenario we could have a [leaderboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet) generated in a similar fashion too.

[image]

Comment: I think we should ban any question that turns from a "recommend me" question into a "what is the earliest example of" question.

Comment: In my experience, most of the questions here that ask for the earliest example of something are either bad questions that get closed quickly, or get only a few replies.  This is a large difference from Golf SE, where good questions often get over thirty replies, and that's actually a good thing there.  So I think enforcing a format wouldn't be worth too much here.  But if you know questions like this with lots of answers here, please tell me.

Comment: One sort of counterexample is http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/96389/ "Which Sci-fi universe uses the most forms of FTL (Faster Than Light)?" where Valorum has already edited the answers.

Comment: @b_jonas - I faced some criticism for doing it. I shan't bother in future. Also, it's worth noting that the vote-scores don't adequately reflect the answer quality, so the whole thing was largely a waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm gonna go with "no", if only because the one time that any effort has been made to implement this...

[Which Sci-fi universe uses the most forms of FTL (Faster Than Light)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96389/which-sci-fi-universe-uses-the-most-forms-of-ftl-faster-than-light)

...the vote-scores haven't shifted to accurately reflect the quality of the answers.

---

Given that the community clearly couldn't care less that one answer is (objectively) better than another when they dole out their (subjectively chosen) votes, creating leaderboards and ranking them using some kind of defined format sounds like a lot of work for no actual benefit.

I have no objection to you *personally* editing all the answers on one of these questions, but I don't think we should try to hold people to an editing standard when there's no discernible upside to doing so.

Answer (score 4):

I think using a standard format for answers to this type of questions would be a good idea.

I propose using

> #### Year: *Title* by A. Author / by D. Director / featuring A. Actor
>
> Explanation what it is and why it fits.

I don't think a leader board is a good idea, though, since it's not a competition. It's up to the querant to decide what the best answer is.

Comment: I think a "leaderboard" could work if it wasn't named leaderboard but something else or just nameless. However, we don't appear to have snippets enabled here anyway so it's likely out of the question.

Comment: A common format is a good idea, keep in mind though that not everything is a book. Would you just do `Year: _Title_` for a  movie? What about a video game, fan fiction, anime/manga? etc. What about on a mixed media question?

Comment: Per my earlier answer, is there any reason to assume that voters will pay any attention to this?

Comment: @Valorum we don't need 100% buy in from every user, just enough that we can enforce it. A custom post notice may go someway to help

Comment: It might be better if we had multiple formats of post titles, separate ones for movies, games, books etc.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - That sounds complicated and largely pointless. I don't object in principle to *you* doing this but I'm dubious if it's gonna have any actual benefit

Comment: I think for the main bold part you just need the year and title. Then to begin the explanation bit you can put the relevant names based on media format.